# How can call a method from another class for Test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to invoke a method from another class using java.
So what i have is a class invoking log method from another class, it's working well.
After this i want to invoke another method from another class to get current url.

So here my classe A and B

question: how can i invoke the method to get thr current url?
Thank you

```
public class A{

    private String url;

    public A(WebDriver driver){       
        url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("The current URL is:"+url);
        Util.wait(5);
        }


public class B {        

@BeforeClass
    public static void Log(){
    //some code here to check if log is ok
    }
@Test
    public void A(){
        A test1 = new A(driver);
        String url2 =test1.A();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a getter and setter for the string url, so you could access it publicly:

```
public String getUrl() {
    return this.url;
}
```

Oh and setter:

```
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

This follows Java Beans conventions by tightly encapsulating fields to the class, but allowing for the data to be unchangeable, OR changeable in allowing only wanted data.

For example you can say that the url can't be longer than 16 characters if you wanted (just as an example):

```
public void setUrl(String url) {
    if (url.length() <= 16)
        this.url = url;
}
```

which would then prevent a change to the url for anything longer than 16 characters in length.

Then you can call it in your test class:

```
@Test
public void getUrl_worksWithUrlLessThan16Length() {
    A test1 = new A(driver);
    String url = "www.google.com";
    A.setUrl(url);
    assertTrue(A.getUrl().equals(url));
}
```

EDIT: There was a request to show further implementation. As follows:

You have two classes, class A and class B. Let's say they're both in their own source code files. So now you have two files that look like this:

**A.java:**

```
public class A {

    private String url;

    public A(WebDriver driver){       
        url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("The current URL is:"+url);
        Util.wait(5);
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {    //THIS IS A SETTER
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {            //THIS IS A GETTER
        return this.url;
    }

}
```

**B.java:**

```
package com.secondClasses.A;

import com.classes.B;

public class B {

A test1;
Webdriver driver;
String url2;

@BeforeClass
public static void Log(){
//some code here to check if log is ok
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    driver = new WebDriver();
    test1 = new A(driver);
}

@After
public void cleanUp() {
    driver = null;
    test1 = null;
    url2 = null;
    System.gc();
}

@Test
public void A(){
    url2 = test1.getUrl();
    assertTrue(url2.equals(url));
}
```

}

There's a few things going on here:

1. You import the class A into class B so you could use it.
2. Create an instance of class A to use.

2a. **(very important point): **Initialize an object reference before any test methods. Notice I said *object reference*.

2b. Instantiate the object in a setUp() or init() method with the annotation @Before which will instantiate the object **before every test method runs**. This helps make our tests independent of each other.

2c. We then dereference the object in the cleanUp() method and *suggest* the garbage collector to run, so we can clear the object off the heap.

3.Then to access the fields of class A, we can use it's getter and setter methods that we have made for it.
  3a. You also need to initialize all fields necessary to pass in the constructor of A, such as the WebDriver. These are initialized in the same way as the objects I spoke about in point 2.

I hope this all helps!

Comment: Here i don't understand what to do and where to put the three first code

Comment: Well, your classes need to be in separate files, or you need to get rid of the public access modifier of class B. You also are missing closing brackets on both classes. See my edit in my post in a few minutes for more and better clarification. @user3610075

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to call `test1.A()`. It's not a method, it's a public constructor of class `A`.

If you need to get `private` variable `url` from another class you can create method:

```
public String getUrl() {
  return this.url;
}
```

and get it in your class `B`, like this:

```
String url2 = test1.getUrl();
```

Comment: If i try your example, it just open a blank page

Comment: @user3610075 But this statement `String url2 = test1.getUrl();` is not for showing you something, it's for store your variable `url` from class `A` to variable `url2`. To show what store in `url2` you need to `System.out.println(test1.getUrl());`. And if `url` variable is not empty, it shows what there is in this variable `url`.

Comment: Thank you Alexander PodKutin, it was very informative for me.

Comment: But i did this:in Class A i added driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl()); and now how can i invoke this in class B, and i forgot to inform i m beginner in webdriver and java